# Incorporating php code into html

Tags: php, html

I am new to web development - however having looked at some tutorials I have been able to create a webpage using php. But I don't think it is very clean and it is not incorporated in html.

How do I incorporate it in html and make it clean. For example I am using `print` for the images. I want to eventually use `jQuery` on the images in my database - to animate them

This is the code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

$query = "SELECT projectName, projectImage FROM projects";      

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$response = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        print
        "<div id= 'item'>" .
        "<p>Project Name ".$row["projectName"]."</p>".
        "<p><img src=".$row["projectImage"]."></p>".
        "</div>";
    }
}
else{

}

?>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: 'Clean' is pretty subjective. Are you trying to separate your HTML and PHP?

Comment: you already are "incorporate it in html"

Comment: You'd be better off posting this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is quite broad of a question but you can use PHP within regular HTML.

For example, you can run some PHP to do some server side calculations and have this in the middle of your html code. See the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Example Test</p>
    <?PHP
    $value1 = 5;
    $value2 = 10;
    $value3 = $value1 + $value2;
    echo "<p>The result is $value3 </p>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

In the code above I used regular HTML and then when I needed to use PHP I used this in the middle and echoed the result so that it is 'printed' as a line of html code.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't how I would recommend structuring my php, but you're new to web development, so now likely isn't the best time to start teaching you about architecture.

You have a couple options.

First, the beauty of php is that you only have to embed it when you need it. For example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My App</title>
        <!-- You can add in any css stylesheets here -->
    </head
    <body>
        <?php             
            $query = "SELECT projectName, projectImage FROM projects";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $response = array();

            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    print
                        "<div id= 'item'>" .
                            "<p>Project Name ".$row["projectName"]."</p>".
                            "<p><img src=".$row["projectImage"]."></p>".
                        "</div>";
                 }
              }
        <!-- You can add in any javascript here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

If you wanted to look into more advanced architectures, the first step would be to separate all of the SQL into another file (ie - build an API). If you did that, you could use something like jQuery (for small projects) to call the relevant API endpoints and then write the returned information to the screen.

The biggest downside to this is that you're going to have to start learning verbs like get and post and how they relate to the crud verbs (create, read, update and delete). This is the basis of REST!